# Batch file fails to remove folder when running Scheduled task

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, privileges

I have a problem I cannot understand so I hope im putting it on the right section of StackNetwork.

I have a batch file.

It dumps data, zips a file and then removes the source folder that was just zipped.

Here are the last steps

```
CD "C:\Backup\%DATE%\"

REM ----- NOW ZIP THE FILE AND DELETE THE SOURCE -----
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -afzip "C:\Backup\%DATE%.zip"

CD "C:\BackUp\"

RMDIR /s /q "C:\BackUp\%DATE%\"
```

This line of code, deletes the folder.

```
    RMDIR /s /q "C:\BackUp\%DATE%\"
```

**The problem is:**

When I **manually** execute the Scheduled task, by right clicking the task and selecting `RUN`, the batch file runs excellent and deletes the folder in the end.

But when the task runs automatically at night, all goes well, **except**, the folder is not deleted.

I assume it has to do with priviliges as it does work when I manually `RUN` the task, but whats funny is that the folder `%DATE%` is being created whitin the batch file.

The task is set to run with highest priviliges, even if the the user is logged in.

Comment: In such cases, I would want to see the output of entire script during the scheduled job (to see where & why it is failing). I will simply remove the "@echo off" in my script and redirect the script output by adding(example) ">>d:\script_op.log" in the scheduled tasks (under Add arguments option). Can you try this?

Comment: A common source for not working deletion of a folder is: any running process has this folder as current working directory. The batch file itself could change directory and make the folder to delete at end the working directory. Or the batch file changes the directory to C:\BackUp\%DATE%\, starts other applications as separate processes which have now this folder as working directory. Then the batch file changes current working directory back to `C:\Backup` and wants to remove the subfolder, but not all started processes have finished and therefore Windows prevents the deletion of the folder.

Comment: I actually do that in the batchfile! I switch to the backup folder.

Answer (score 6):

Before I write about my ideas for possible reasons on directory deletion failure, I suggest to use in batch file:

```
RMDIR /s /q "C:\BackUp\%TODAY%\" 2>"C:\BackUp\RemoveDirError.log"
```

Look on `"C:\BackUp\RemoveDirError.log"` after next scheduled task run which should contain the error message being hopefully helpful on finding the reason for failed deletion of the directory.

---

### 1. DATE different between beginning and end of batch execution

The value of environment variable **DATE** is always the current date.

The value of **DATE** at beginning of batch file would be different to value on end of the batch file if this batch file is executed over midnight.

Example:

The batch file is started on 23:30:00 every day and needs 50 minutes to complete.

The batch code on execution would be in this case for example:

```
CD "C:\Backup\2014-09-08\"

REM ----- NOW ZIP THE FILE AND DELETE THE SOURCE -----
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -afzip "C:\Backup\2014-09-08.zip"

CD "C:\Backup\"

RMDIR /s /q "C:\Backup\2014-08-10\"
```

*Note: Format of date string depends on Windows language settings for date.*

The result is the error message:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

The solution for this problem is to assign value of **DATE** to a new variable at beginning of the batch file and reference this variable instead of **DATE** in entire batch file.

```
set TODAY=%DATE%
CD "C:\Backup\%TODAY%\"

REM ----- NOW ZIP THE FILE AND DELETE THE SOURCE -----
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -afzip "C:\Backup\%TODAY%.zip"

CD "C:\BackUp\"

RMDIR /s /q "C:\BackUp\%TODAY%\"
```

The environment variable **TODAY** contains here the date string definitely not changed during the execution of the batch file.

---

### 2. WinRAR is started as separate process

Another problem could be that **WinRAR** is a Windows application and not a console application and could be therefore executed in a separate process executed parallel to the batch file with `C:\BACKUP\%DATE%\` as current working directory.

The batch job would continue execution immediately after string **WinRAR** in this case and this is the reason deleting the directory is prevented by Windows.

The solution is to use command `start` with option `/wait` to force running **WinRAR** as separate process but halt execution of batch job until **WinRAR** has terminated itself after finishing compression.

```
set TODAY=%DATE%
CD "C:\Backup\%TODAY%\"

REM ----- NOW ZIP THE FILE AND DELETE THE SOURCE -----
start "Backup Compression" /wait /min "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -afzip "C:\Backup\%TODAY%.zip"

CD "C:\BackUp\"

RMDIR /s /q "C:\BackUp\%TODAY%\"
```

But this is most likely not the reason as in this case the deletion of the folder would fail also on running the scheduled task manually.

---

### 3. WinRAR outputs a question and no one answers it

It is possible that **WinRAR** detects a problem during compression and opens a message prompt with a question to answer by the user. As on scheduled task execution nobody answers it, **WinRAR** holds compression for an unusual long time.

The solution would be adding `-y` to **WinRAR** command line in batch file.

```
start "Backup Compression" /wait /min "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -afzip -y "C:\Backup\%TODAY%.zip"
```

Again I think, this is not very likely for not deleting the directory.

---

I have no more ideas. We would need to see complete batch file code if nothing above helps to find the reason for error on deletion of the directory on running the batch file as automatically executed scheduled task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mofi. Im testing your suggestions right now!

Comment: ive found the reason, it was because my 3:rd party backup software was running at this time, hence using the folder i was trying to delete. They were overlapping each other. Thanks for you time.

Comment: @GalDreiman I think, [Kay Nelson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/606294/kay-nelson) has one scheduled task started at a specific time to create the backup and another scheduled task started later to run the batch file. This second scheduled task was started before the backup operation finished. So the solution was most likely starting second scheduled task for running the batch file some minutes later.